# SLIM h3 inside p

Tags: slim-lang

If I want to put header tag h1..h5 into p it render HTML in wrong way:

slim

```
p
  h3 Header here
  span Just text
```

expected

```
<p>
   <h3>Header here</h3>
  <span>Just text</span>
</p>
```

in real it render

```
<p></p>
  <h3>Header here</h3>
  <span>Just text</span>
<p></p>
```

looks like nothing special but in this case I can't bind CSS style because structure renders in broken way.

Is it a bug? Or I can solve this in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not define tags like `h3` and `span` inside the `p` tag.
See [HTML5 specification](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#the-p-element) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Slim itself doesn’t care about the tags, and renders your code as you expect:

```
$ slimrb
p
  h3 Header here
  span Just text
```

produces:

```html
<p><h3>Header here</h3><span>Just text</span></p>
```

which matches what your expected code, except for whitespace.

This isn’t valid HTML though, so when the browser parses it it will correct it to something valid. For example the Chrome inspector will show:

```html
<p></p>
<h3>Header here</h3>
<span>Just text</span>
<p></p>
```

Where the browser has closed the `p` element before the next `h3` element.

If you want this to work in the browser, make sure you are generating valid HTML. Perhaps use a `div` instead of a `p`?